# Construction of appropriate Morse functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

I am interested in the properties of connectedness of level sets of Morse functions. Let $M$ a compact smooth $n$-manifold, and $1\leq k<n$. Is it possible to construct $k$ Morse functions $f_1,\cdots,f_k:M\rightarrow [0,1]$ on $M$ such that for $\mathscr{L}^k$ almost every $t\in [0,1]^k$,
$$
\bigcap_{j=1}^k f_j^{-1}\{t_j\}
$$
is a connected $(n-k)$ submanifold? (of course $\mathrm{Im} f_j=[0,1]$) The case $k=n-1$ is of primary interest for me, and even $n=2$ would be interesting. For example, il we take a $2$-sphere, if $x_3$ if the third coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then except in $-1$ and $1$, we have a connected curve, but if we take for example $f(x)=(x_3-\frac{1}{2})^2$, then $f^{-1}\{t\}$ is the union of two circles, the equator if $t=\frac{1}{2}$ or the empty set, so we cannot choose arbitrary Morse functions in this construction, if it is possible.

Comment: Do you call the empty set connected? If not, then the answer is no when $k>1$.

Comment: I do not think that the empty set is much relevant here. The $f_j$ are surjective, so for almost every $t\in [0,t]$, $f^{-1}\{t\}$ is a non-empty submanifold. But for surfaces, does your answer mean that there is always a Morse function such that $f^{-1}\{t\}$ is a circle for almost every $t\in [0,1]$?

Comment: Excuse me Mr. Bourrigan, I forgot to precise this. I edited my question, so the answer to yours is yes.

Comment: Well, actually it's not very important. The only (compact connected oriented) surface with such a Morse function is the 2-sphere (so the answer to your question is 'no'). Basically, your hypothesis prevents $f$ to have index 1 critical points (=saddle points) because the local model shows that just above or just below such a critical point, one of the level set is nonconnected. So your function only has minima and maxima. From there, it's quite easy to show that it's the sphere (for example the formula giving the Euler characteristic from the indices of the crit.pts show that χ>0).

Comment: I think you would be very interested by the notion of Reeb graph of a Morse function. (Some googling gives "Computational Topology" by Edelsbrunner and Harer as a reference).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bourrigan, and if I replace connected by admits $k(n)$ connected composants almost everywhere, does this work? (with an explicit $k=k(n)$) I knew the theorem about the sphere you mentionned, thanks again for your help.

Comment: For a surface, yes. If you take the standard picture of a surface as sitting in $\mathbb R^3$, you can easily find a projection for which every level is either empty, a point, a circle, a "8" (two circles joined by a point) or two circles.

Comment: My point is that if for almost every $(t_1,\dots ,t_k)$ the set $\cap f_j^{-1}(t_j)$ is nonempty then by continuity they are all nonempty; while on the other hand the set $f_1^{-1}(0)$ is finite and $f_2$ can take only finitely many value on this finite set.

Comment: @MaximeBourrigan: The function you describe isn't a Morse function; I gave a construction of an appropriate Morse function in my answer below; I'm not sure how to do this by a projection from an embedding in $R^3$.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Goodwillie, I had not seen your last comment, so it seems that the answer is negative if $k>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n>1$ and $k=1$ this is possible (contrary to a comment above). Choose a Morse function that has a single minimum and a single maximum (I assume your $M$ is connected!).  If $n=2$, assume also that you pass all of the index $1$ critical points simultaneously (ie each the index $1$ critical level is one point). Then the level set just above the index $1$ critical level is still connected, even in dimension $2$ (paradoxically, the hardest case for this argument). So for $n=2$ we are done.

It's probably easier to visualize this case ($k=1$) in terms of handles; I'm just saying to add the $1$-handles simultaneously in dimension $2$.  Recall that passing an index $d$ critical point means that you do a surgery on a $d-1$ sphere, and this doesn't disconnect the level set unless $d=n-1$. So after passing the critical levels of index $< n-1$, you have a connected level set. On the other hand, if there's only one $n$-handle (one maximum) then for $n>2$ the level set after any $n-1$ handle is still connected.

You might be able to do the case $n=3$, $k=2$ by similar naive arguments, ie choose a Morse function on your 3-manifold where there is only one index $1$ (resp. $2$) critical level, and then look for a family of Morse functions on the family of surfaces sweeping out your 3-manifold, each with connected level sets.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Ruberman, I will try to fill in the blanks by myself and let this question opened for a more few days if there is a more complete answer.